# Prestashop, what does this parameter "callerElement" means in ajaxCart method?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

In Prestashop, what does this parameter "callerElement" means in this method ?

```
ajaxCart.add = function(idProduct, idCombination, addedFromProductPage, callerElement, quantity, whishlist
```

I don’t find the answer in the [Prestashop documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/English+documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to see what is this parameter is to display it in the debugbar of your browser :

```
console.log(callerElement)
```

This parameter is the DOM element you clicked to add product in cart.

Comment: When i add console.log(callerElement), i have an error in console : "ReferenceError: callerElement is not defined. I guess i'm missing something.

Comment: Is there something to add to the custom button "add to the cart" in html or in JS ?

Answer (score 1):

"callerElement" is the html element on which you click for "add to cart"

eg.

on product detail page when some one click on "add to cart" button then porduct image fly to cart.

here "add to cart" button or "add to cart" span tag is "callerElement".

Comment: Thanx, I understand very well. But in concrete terms, what could be this parameter ? If i use a custom button (not the native add to cart button) and use ajaxCart.add, how do i know this parameter ?

Comment: You have to add a reference to the button you are using (your custom button). E.g. If you are within an event of that button, you can use the "this" reference.